# JQuery selector didnt see class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have following problem.

If I have this structure:

`<table class="test hidden" id="test1"></table>
var table = $("test1");`

then everything is ok.

But If have this structure:

`<table class="test test1 hidden"></table>
var table = $(".test1");`

then jQuery return NULL. Where can be problem? Thanks

Comment: var table = $("test1"); work really ?
var table = $("#test1"); must work

Comment: Hmm is your page loading jquery well ?

Comment: var table = $(".test1"); should work. You should post more code to see where your problem resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the HTML is :

```
<table class="test hidden" id="test1"></table>
```

The following code will not work because you don't specify if `test1` is a `class` or `id` :

```
var table = $("test1");
```

Should be :

```
var table = $("#test1"); //id selector
//OR
var table = $(".test"); //class selector
```

For `<table class="test test1 hidden"></table>` the following selectors should works :

```
var table = $(".test1");
var table = $(".test");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$(".test1") works correctly at my end. Check this fiddle:

```
alert($(".test1").length);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/htfthv6f/